# Use UIMenuItem inside UItableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uimenuitem

I am new user as iPhone developer, actually I want to use UIMenuItem inside UITableView and I'm trying to achieve below image.

[image]

I want to create some shadow effect which you can see in the bottom of table view. If I put one image on the tableView then I cant get click of that cell. So I'm trying [How to set the alpha of newly inserted UITableViewCell to 0 for short duration](http://www.developersite.org/101-39983-ios).

please guide me.
Thank you..

Comment: If you put a image view to apply shadow on tableview, you can still be able to click on cell. but make sure you have image view user interaction to be false.